# Java force panel certain size

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

When I add a JPanel, whose size should be (300, 300), to my main JFrame, the entire JFrame is (300, 300), which should not be. The JPanel itself should be (300, 300).

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Tester extends JFrame {

    public Tester() {
        this.getContentPane().add(new Window());
        this.pack();

        addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                formMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
    }

    private void formMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                  
        System.out.println("x: " + evt.getX() + ", y: " + evt.getY());
    }  

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Tester().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Window extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(300, 300);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When I put `Dimension d = this.getSize();
        System.out.println(String.format("Dimension: %1s,%2s", d.width, d.height));` immediately after `this.pack();` I see `Dimension: 316,338` as output..

Comment: BTW - 1 upvote for posting MCVE.

Comment: +Andrew Thompson MCVE is recommended according to the Stack Overflow rules. Please remove the -1.

Comment: (sigh) What I **should** have written (to be understood) is (perhaps) *"BTW: 1 upvote for posting MCVE."*. If I had **down voted,** I might have written *"BTW: 1 **downvote** for posting MCVE."*.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Understood. Thank you.

Comment: @Arc, rather than worrying about upvote/downvote, maybe you should be commenting on the help you have received. Is your problem solved or not?

Comment: ... How big is the JFrame post to be?

Answer (score 1):

> the entire JFrame is (300, 300), which should not be.

Why do you say this? If you click at the bottom right you will see values greater than 300.

Maybe what you want is:

```
    //this.getContentPane().add(new Window());
    JPanel panel = new Window();
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);
    this.pack();
    //addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    panel.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
```

Now all the mouse points will be relative to the panel.

Answer (score 1):

The default layout for `JFrame` is `BorderLayout` , and when you add component without specifying the region, it will go by default to the `center` region, and the center region *doesn't respect* the preferred size of its component.

Regarding the the size of the frame, the pack method calculate it based on the internal components preferred sizes.